# how to load image in canvas from cache in chrome?

Tags: javascript

I am using a canvas to put 2 images on each other with the top one having a specific opacity.
Additionally I have a slider that controls the opacity level. My problem is that when I change the slider (`input` event) the "final" image doesn't update fast enough because the canvas doesn't load the 2nd image from the cache leading to more problems.
In firefox it works perfectly.

Here is my code to draw the canvas (it will be redrawn each time I use the slider since I don't know any other way to update the transparency)

```
var opacity = 0.4;
var url1 = 'foo.jpg';
var url2 = 'bar.jpg';
var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var myImg1 = new Image();
myImg1.onload = function() {
    myCanvas.width = this.width;
    myCanvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.drawImage(myImg1, 0, 0);
    var myImg2 = new Image();
    myImg2.onload = function() {
        ctx.globalAlpha = opacity;
        ctx.drawImage(myImg2, 0, 0);
    };
    myImg2.src = url2;
};
myImg1.src = url1;
```

Edit:
I can't reproduce this behavior while using jsfiddle since the images are cached there. I still don't know how to fix it in my dev enviroment since it works in firefox and I am not aware of any cashing logics.
Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ewnhfz7g/

Comment: _"because the canvas doesn't load the 2nd image from the cache leading to more problems"_ - What is this assumption based on?

Comment: based on trial :) Like I said: If I change the slider the image takes a while to load, depending on the network speed. If I change the slider further while the image from the previous step is not loaded it leads to opacity bugs where the opacity is like 0 and the bottom line image is not visible at all. But I guess that's something different that has to do with the event. Still, I don't have this issue in firefox where the image is loaded immediatly. I cannot move the slider fast enough to produce something like that in firefox.

Comment: Preload the image and check if this makes it any better. If not then it is not related to that part of your script.

Comment: what do you mean by "preloading"? Putting the "img.src" part before the onload event? Doesn't work.
Also this part of the script is pretty much the script. The rest is just the slider event calling this function.

Comment: I just noticed that I don't have this problem in jsfiddle. So I guess it's some caching problem? I still don't know how to solve it then and why it only affects chrome and not firefox..I added this to my question